# Posterior Predictive Check for Hierarchical Logistic Regression Model

Tags: bayesian, goodness-of-fit, hierarchical-bayesian, bugs

I need to apply **Posterior Predictive Check (PPC)** on Hierarchical Logistic Regression Model (so I have binary outcome) to validate my model (to see goodness of fit of my model). I know that I need to simulate *replicated data* from the Posterior Predictive Distribution of my model and compute a test statistics (*discrepancy*), so that I can compare that with the one I compute from my observations. If my model is good than the PPD of my data should generate same sample as my observations...

I believe, I understood the concept of PPC correctly, but the thing is I am not sure about what test statistics can be selected for Bernoulli distribution. I waiting your recommendations (with reasons if it is possible)with respect to that. I would be much appreciated if you also could help me how to implement the computation of the statistics on Winbugs/OpenBUGS.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Maybe the explanation [here](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597C/lectures/ppc.pdf) is of any help?

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped a lot. It is very well articulated!